# Are there any libraries which helping work with svg in .net?

Tags: .net, svg

Are there any libraries which helping work with svg in .net?

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is An SVG framework in C# and an SVG-GDI+ bridge

I used it before and it helped me too much 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/svgnet.aspx

Comment: Yes, I also have seen it, Don't you think it very old? Is it supported?

Comment: this project was started 2003 and they are making updates from time to time ,it facilitate the processing and particularly the creation of SVG documents in C# , it uses the original svg classes in C# and these classes havent changed since .net framework 3.5